# Codelyzer no more showing TSLint errors on the browser console?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tslint

I am using TSlint for my angular project along with angular-cli and codelyzer. All of a sudden I have stopped seeing the Linted messages on the browser console. I dont know what has changed but the messages I generally used to see on the Browser Console are gone. I dont see the lint's message. How should I rectify this?